# How can I compute a mathematical formula for my CNN?

Tags: math, conv-neural-network, computation

Let's say, for example, I have built the following CNN model using Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I wish to be able to transform the above model into a mathematical formula.

---

I understand the basic structure of a CNN as follows:

[image: CNN recursive formula]

where

[image: definitions for used values]
[image]

---

However, I do not know how to go from the above recursive formula to something like this (the first two summations are weights and the second two are adjustable biases):

[image]

---

- Do I need to trace each weight, each bias and each connection of every neuron? If so, how?
- Furthermore, I would highly appreciate it if someone could provide a generalized strategy for tackling such a problem (like finding a math formula to suit a different kind of classifier).
- Lastly, is this an easy task and is it a worthwhile one?

Comment: Can you give more details about every part of the formula?

Comment: @Wenbo I have taken the formula from the internet so I would not be able to give a great explanation of what it represents. I believe w_k is the feature filter and that the formula resembles the process of feature extraction and fusion. In essence, however, my question asks how one can transform the code given above into a formula that resembles something like the one shown. Note, however, that the formula shown is just an example and not representative of the code given above.